# Converse of Gelbart-Jacquet lift for $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ Maass forms

Tags: automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

(This question is migrated from MSE)

Gelbart-Jacquet lift gives functoriality from $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ that corresponds to a symmetric square map $\mathrm{Sym}^{2}: \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \to \mathrm{GL}(3, \mathbb{C})$.
In the aspects of Maass forms, it gives a way to construct a $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ Maass form from a given $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ Maass form.
In Goldfeld's book "Automorphic forms and $L$-functions on $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$", he introduces a quite explicit proof of symmetric square lifting for $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ Maass forms, using converse theorem.

Ramakrishnan proved a converse of the Gelbart-Jacquet lift, which states that all the cuspidal *self-dual* $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ automorphic representations comes from symmetric square of $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ automorphic forms (up to quadratic twist). The proof in his paper uses Ginzburg-Rallis-Soundry's decent theory (with a comment that the fact itself was known to experts, which can be proven by using stable trace formula, although I can't find any reference for that...).

What I tried is to re-prove the Ramakrishnan's result for $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ Maass forms, using converse theorems or whatsoever. I found that one may need converse theorem for Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions, which seems intractable. I also tried to directly construct the candidate $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ Maass form via Fourier coefficient, but still don't know how to prove the automorphy of the candidate function. Are there any good references (if exists) for such result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Ramakrishnan gives you what you want - why are you trying to give a different proof of this?

Comment: @PeterHumphries For the Gelbart-Jacquet lifting itself, it was helpful for me to understand their proof by understanding the result for Maass forms (in Goldfeld’s book) first. I want to do the same approach for the Ramakrishnan’s result by trying to prove the result for Maass forms first, but I couldn’t do it myself.

Comment: Sure, but isn't the proof in Goldfeld's book the same as that of Gelbart-Jacquet except written classically instead of adelically? Ramakrishnan's proof that self-dual $\mathrm{GL}_3$ automorphic representations arise as Gelbart-Jacquet lifts from $\mathrm{GL}_2$ automorphic forms does *not* use the converse theorem, so why would you expect to be able to prove the result classically in this way?

Comment: @PeterHumphries I think there's one more difference between the Gelbart-Jacquet's original proof and Goldfeld's classical proof - the former one is over general number field but the latter one is over $\mathbb{Q}$ (maybe I'm wrong). Also, I actually do not expect to prove Ramakrishnan's result with converse theorem.

Comment: I think I need to change my question in a following way: if we only consider Maass forms of $\mathrm{GL}(3)$, can Ramakrishnan's result proved in a classical way? More precisely, for given self-dual Maass form of $\mathrm{GL}(3)$, can we construct a corresponding $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ Maass form and show its automorphy without adelic language?

Comment: In answer to your last question, it is not hard to construct the corresponding $\mathrm{GL}_2$ form in terms of its Hecke eigenvalues and Laplacian eigenvalue. But for showing its automorphy? I don't know - maybe with a ton of work, one could de-adelise Ramakrishnan's proof. But also I don't know why on earth you would want to do this - why deprive yourself of useful tools? It'd be tying one hand behind your back.